# What does the state "disputed" means for a flag?

Tags: discussion, flagging

This may be a trivial question, but I cannot figure exactly what the status "*disputed*" means for a flag:

- "*helpful*" means that the flag as been considered as justified and useful for the community,
- "*declined*" is the opposite,
- "*disputed*" = ???

I initially thought this was a transitional state like "*pending*": the flag has been seen but something is going-on to determine whether this flag will finally be considered "*helpful*" or "*declined*".

However it seems I'm wrong and that "*disputed*" is a final state in its own right.

I mostly get this state when flagging answers left by new members who have not enough rep to comments other people's posts (btw I also wonder if there shouldn't be two different flags to distinguish between posts to delete and posts to keep and move as comments, merging the two within a unique flag just make it confusing).

Concrete examples:

- [James Fox asking the OP more details about his firewall and port forwarding configuration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/101003/upgrade-shell-to-meterpreter-behind-nat/101246#101246) (this one is recent and is still an answer),
- [Mike W added supplementary information and a personal example to the OP post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/100945/is-there-any-way-my-password-is-hashed-if-im-only-ever-asked-to-provide-5-out/101097#101097) (this one is older and is now moved to a comment, so my flag was somehow "accepted", however the flag still remains in "*disputed*" state as mentioned above which leads me to conclude this is a final state and not a transitional one).

Comment: This is explained in this MSO answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95277/167831

Comment: Thanks ! (I wonder how I missed it...)